# How to use CF cards in a Kyocera FS-1010?

Tags: printer, compact-flash

I have a Kyocera Mita FS-1010 b/w office laser printer. The printer accepts CF cards, supposedly for adding fonts and things like templates or something.

I was looking through the manuals (both user, and service manuals) but the instructions only go as far as to describe how to actually install a CF card into the printer.

- What filesystem does it have to have (and what directory structure)?
- What exactly can I put on it (what kind of files, and where)?
- Is there any way, how I can use the CF card for buffering workload, for instance when printing large PDFs?

I have a 512MB Type-I CF card, that fits nicely into the CF slot just below the network card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With printers from ***Kyocera*** you can store **font-files**, macros, "PRN files" and the such on the Compact Flash card. Insert it as described in the manual and fill it wit *Kyocera's* ["IC-Link" utility](http://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.de/index/serviceworld/downloadcenter.html?initial=false&search=any&searchTerm=iclink&category=).

As for the **font-files, TTF** is among the supported formats. If you have, for example, PFB or OTF ones you can convert them using the free open-source software FontForge.

Storing them on the printer (CF, memory…) will theoretically speed up printing *lots of small documents with different fonts*, because your PC can skip sending the fonts along with the document. You will notice a benefit only for very large ones, though — the most popular fonts/typefaces consist of just a few font-files with about 50–120kb and your printer is most probably connected by a relatively fast connection capable of transferring them in milliseconds.

Another use-case for a CF card are **"PRN files"**. That's basically **frozen print-jobs** (most probably forms or pamphlets) which you can replay without your PC, using the printer alone.

For current *Kyocera* printers, you can store **up to 256 different resources** on the CF card. Speed of the card doesn't matter, because the bottleneck is the printer which reads/writes them at about 0.1 MB/s — max. Unless you use very large font-files (e.g., typeface *[FFF Tusj](http://www.dafont.com/fff-tusj.font)*) you will barely fill 30–40 MB of your CF card.

**Print-jobs are not cached using the CF card**. For that you can have your printer **create a RAM-disk in internal memory**. The effect will be that your print queue on the OS will be empty sooner, and multiple copies of large documents will print faster. (A single large print-job won't benefit from the RAM-disk at all. To the contrary, it might get not printed at all if it doesn't fit into the RAM-disk. If in doubt don't use one.)

Fonts are cached in internal memory, too, once sent by your operating system. Therefore, if you really want to pimp your printer, better buy more internal memory.

Comment: This looks like it's copy-and-pasted from a support site somewhere, and doesn't actually address a lot of the points in the original question.  Can you tailor this to provide more useful detail?

Comment: English is not my first language, so I take this as compliment. Thank you!

Comment: Your English is very good, yes.  But let me be clear - *I don't think this answers the question very well*.  I did not upvote it for that reason.  Most notably you don't say anything about filesystem or directory structure, the very first thing that's being asked...

Comment: Two of the three points of the question have been addressed. Unfortunately I don't know the file-system — but have given a link to the program which is used to utilize CF cards. You can format and fill the CF card using it, too.

In addition to his questions @polemon implied he wants to improve his experience with the printer. I hope to have illuminated all the options he or other readers have in a similar situation and added value beyond what has been asked about a month ago.

And no — I am not affiliated in any way with Kyocera, HP etc.

Comment: I don't see how this isn't a fine answer? Yeah it might not be complete for a reason or two, but it gives good information? People these days are just so darn negative all the time on the internet... Forums are dying because of this.

Comment: I finally managed to test the TTF capabilities, and yeah, you're right. it does speed up printing, marginally. Unfortunately, as you mentioned, it's not possible to use the CF cards for caching, so it's kind of useless. But it was a nice use-case exercise, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Your printer may be different, but from my experience these CF cards are purchased from and provided by the manufacturer.  They are not designed for end-users to put their own data on.

Comment: Hmm, maybe someone reverse-engineered it?

Comment: I concur. And, as for buffering, printers just don't work that way. The only printers that can use a (hard) disk to buffer jobs are the ones with Fiery drivers. If anything, using a local disk to buffer slows the printer down, because it still has to receive and process the data as usual, but there are the extra steps of storing to disk and retrieving as well.

Comment: It seems to be actually possible to format the CF card while it's in the printer. Supposedly it loads everything from the CF card into internal memory on boot. I'm really beginning to wonder if there aren't files, that can be simply copied onto the CF card.